# PrePopulate Fields in Oracle Login Screen

Tags: oracleforms

I have an Oracle Forms Web Application which runs on an applet. The login screen is the default Oracle Login form containing Username, Password and Database fields.

Is there any way to auto populate the Username and Database fields based on the URL so that users just need to enter the password every time they open the application?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the LOGON buil-in on On-Logon trigger for this, example is below:

Write a form level On-Logon Trigger as following:

```
LOGON('yourusername','@dbstring');
```